# Why is scala match.error thrown?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm trying to understand pattern-matching by writing a simple example. Here it is:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) = {
  val tsm = new Test[Number]
    tsm.foo(tsm.Val(10))
}

class Test[T <: Any] {
  def foo(t: Any): Unit = {
    val f: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = (_: Any) match {
      case Val(s) => println("Val" + s)
      case Sup(l) => println("Sup" + l)
    }
    f()
  }

  class Val(val t: T)
  class Sup(val l: Number)

  object Val{
    def apply(t: T): Val = new Val(t)
    def unapply(arg: Val): Option[T] = Some(arg.t)
  }
  object Sup{
    def unapply(arg: Sup): Option[Number] = Some(arg.l)
  }
}
```

But the code throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: () (of class scala.runtime.BoxedUnit)
    at scala.PartialFunction$$anon$1.apply(PartialFunction.scala:253)
    at scala.PartialFunction$$anon$1.apply(PartialFunction.scala:251)
    at com.test.Test$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(Test.scala:7)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at com.test.Test.foo(Test.scala:11)
    at com.test.App$.main(App.scala:6)
    at com.test.App.main(App.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

I don't quite understand it. I created an object of type `Val(10)` and passed it into `foo`. I expected it printed `Val10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define a function `f: PartialFunction[Any, Unit]` which takes an argument of type `Any` and then call it `f()` with no arguments. If you replace `f()` with `f(t)` (which is what I think you intended) everything works.

Comment: @user3663882 Well if you run `scalac` with `-deprecation`, you get a nice warning about it at least: warning: `Adaptation of argument list by inserting () has been deprecated: this is unlikely to be what you want.
        signature: Function1.apply(v1: T1): R
  given arguments: <none>
 after adaptation: Function1((): Unit)
    f()`

Answer (score 2):

When you call f() (last line of foo) you haven't passed t so instead it thinks you passed (). Did you mean f(t)?

By the way [T <: Any] is redundant. You could just say [T].